# Rails Kaminari pagination error with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am Using Ransack with Kaminari  - My Controller is:

```
def index 
  @q = Household.search(params[:q])
  @households = @q.result
end
```

The relevant part of my view:

```
- @households.each do |household|
    %tr
      %td= link_to household.household_name, edit_household_path(household)
      %td= household.box
      %td= household.thumbs.html_safe
      %td= household.neighbors.count
      %td= household.visits.count
      %td= household.last_visit
      %td
        = link_to 'Edit', edit_household_path(household), class: 'btn'
        = link_to 'Destroy', household, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete, class:    'btn btn-mini btn-danger'
  = paginate @households
```

This give me an error:

```
undefined method `current_page' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd4cd3a0b98>
```

If I change

```
= paginate @households
```

to

```
= paginate households
```

I am OK but I only get pagination when I execute a search, when I have a blank I don't get any  pagination  - I am using decent exposure which is allowing my household instead of @household

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your controller as follows.

```
def index 
  @q = Household.search(params[:q])
  @households = @q.result.page(params[:page]).per(5)
end
```