# Understanding "@books = Book.all.page params[:page]" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, parameters, controller

looooong time reader and knowledge attainer, first time poster. I've started learning Rails and I definitely need help.

I am following a tutorial with this code:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @books = Book.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
    else
      @books = Book.all.page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

And I am trying to apply this to my own project (I have 'destinations' not 'books'). What I don't understand is what is the *.page* parameter and where is it generated from?

I am getting an *"undefined method "page"* on my Controller and I don't understand what it is.

This is my code:

```
class DestinationsController < ApplicationController
def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @destination = Destination.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])
    else
      @destination = Destination.all.page params[:page]
    end
  end
```

The only field I have in the Destinations table is country. I thought maybe that could replace it but alas, no. Yes, I'm very new to this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That is from ***pagination gems*** either `will_paginate` or `kaminari`

Comment: You have to install either of the two for you to work.

Comment: Thank you, you pointed me in the right direction but after many hours, there was a space in a link to a javascript file causing the main issue. However, thank you I now know about pagination parameters! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How deep is your programming knowledge, especially Ruby one?

The tutorial is clearly using a pagination gem, I'll take [kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) because it's the one I use.

The gem monkey patches relation to include the method `page` and `per`, and as you can clearly see in Kaminari homepage, the method simply accepts `page(page_number)` and will take care to split your records using SQL `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. The `params[:page]` will be a simple `HTTP GET` param `?page=12`.

I notice you are also using `Destination.search`, that's not standard, did you create it? If yes, it should probably be something like `Destination.search(params[:query]).page(params[:page])`. If however it's using something like [meta_search](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/meta_search) (which you shouldn't) or [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), they are quite advanced and you should check for compatibility with Kaminari, which I'm quite sure it's present in Ransack

Comment: Thanks @Fire-Dragon-DoL... I am a frontend developer and this is my first forray into the deep mysteries of the backend. As far as I can see, I have used: 'Destination.search(params[:query]).page(params[:page])' unless I am not understanding you. Thanks for the tips and yes I assumed it was pagination but didn't mention it.

Comment: From the code I'm seeing no, you didn't use `search.page`, in your question you clearly write `Book.search(params[:query], page: params[:page])` (page passed as param, not chained). To use it with Ransack, which I suppose you are using, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17463115/312907 In the end, it's your choice if you want pagination for those records or not. If yes, you should add `gem 'kaminari'` to your Gemfile at least and fix the pagination for ransack as I suggested

Comment: "page passed as param, not chained". I see that now. I have a lot to learn. Thank you for the help.